# Flutter - VideoPlayer - Support http headers while constructing video controller from network datasource

Tags: http, flutter, dart, http-headers, video-player

I want to add http headers to video controller from network to pass bearer token to let watch video for only authorized users, I found issue about it on github official flutter repo https://github.com/flutter/plugins/pull/2121 and here also https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16466 nothing is moving on and I need this feature. Is there any way to inject http headers before sending the request for video?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this package called [video player with header](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player_header#-readme-tab-)

Answer (score 2):

Now, the `video_player` plugin supports adding `httpHeaders` while opening videos from the network.

###### Example:

```dart
VideoPlayerController.network(
    'your-video-url',
    httpHeaders: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ...',
    },
);
```

Comment: This does not seem to work on the `web` platform. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [better_player](https://pub.dev/packages/better_player) as it provides the network headers feature.

```
var dataSource = BetterPlayerDataSource(
  BetterPlayerDataSourceType.network,
  "https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerBlazes.mp4",
  subtitles: BetterPlayerSubtitlesSource(
    type: BetterPlayerSubtitlesSourceType.file,
    url: "${directory.path}/example_subtitles.srt",
  ),
  headers: {"header":"my_custom_header"}
);
```

[video_player_header](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player_header) is not maintained for a long time as mentioned by Christian X (AndroidX support is missing)